# Concurrent photo and note uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, concurrency, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have this requirement whereby the user is uploading a photo from the phone, and typing a note along with the photo

However, to vastly improve responsiveness, I would like to start uploading the photo before the user has finished typing the note (the same technique instagram uses)

So, there are 3 scenarios:
- the photo uploading finishes, then the note is submitted
- the note is submitted, then the photo finishes uploading
- the note and photo finishes uploading at the same time

I am using a unique token, as well as after_create hooks now to check and save.

- a unique uuid comes along with both the photo upload and the note
- store the photo in a temporary store with the uniqueid

  - when the photo is saved (after_create), check if there are any notes with the uniqueid. If so, attach the photo to note.
- store the note with the uniqueid

  - when the note is saved (after_create), check if there are any photos with the uniqueid. If so, attach note to photo

This seems like a rather common problem, and I am wondering whether there are any accepted patterns / solutions around this? I am using mongoid and rails 3.2

Comment: I think you have to distinct presentation layer from app layer. Also instagram is a very bad example considering web app because it's native and can easily do things you can't do (at all or with great effort). In native app case there are also less security concerns as user cannot edit params being sent to the server (as is clearly the case with your example).

In one of my apps I just lock the submit button until photo upload finishes. This is a pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid concurrency problems, and UI confusions. What I would do, in your case, is:

- User choses the photo -> set local variable in JS(client) -> servers starts uploading the photo
  ( when server respond back from the photo upload, unset the local js var )
- User write notes
- User submits the form -> you check if the js variable is set or not, if it is, means that photo was not uploaded yet, so you show a message. Otherwise you just submit the form with the note.

If you simplify your flow to be something like that, you should not have too much edgecases to have to debug and fix.

The only potential risk in here, is a 'deadlock' case, lets say for some reason server never send back a response to client, which never unset the js var. To avoid those cases you could have a big timeout on the client, that if there server dont respond within that timeout you show an error message.